# Get XML data with PHP. Stuck?

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to get the latest comment from an xml. An example can be found here: http://dev.smoige.com/discussion.xml?DiscussionID=8. I managed to get the LastCommentID which let's say is 37, can be found in this format `<CommentID>37</CommentID>` and under that there is this: `<Body>this is my damn comment!</Body>` which I'm really after. How can I use the LastCommentID to select the right CommentID and get it's body?

Help please.

```
$latestXml = 'http://dev.smoige.com/discussion.xml?DiscussionID='.$Discussion->DiscussionID;

        if(!$xml=simplexml_load_file($latestXml)){
            trigger_error('Error reading XML file',E_USER_ERROR);
        }

    foreach($xml as $user){
        $last = $user->LastCommentID.' ';

    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: XPath.

Here's a great tutorial:

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-XML-Tutorial-P848.html

```
<?php
  $xml = simplexml_load_file("books.xml")
       or die("Error: Cannot create object");
  // we want to show just <title> nodes
  foreach($xml->xpath('//title') as $title){
    echo $title. "<br />";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help man. Wasn't able to do anything, but i'll keep trying.